# Does Aliasing/Alignment issues occur for an Array within a Structure?

Tags: c, structure, strict-aliasing

If we have an array within a struct:

```
struct Names
{
   uint8 fileId;
   uint8 name[50];
};
```

and then we try to assign a uint16 from the array to a uint16 variable like:

```
uint16 someName = *((uint16 *)&NamesObj.name[21]);
```

Will this violate aliasing rule/alignment rules and lead to undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this violates C rules. The objects in `name` are `uint8` (presumably some unsigned 8-bit integer type), and they are accessed through a pointer to `uint16` (presumably some 16-bit integer type).

The relevant part of the 2011 C standard, from draft N1570, is 6.5 7:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:
>
> — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
>
> — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
>
> — a character type.

The type `uint16` is none of these.

Comment: But how would it lead to undefined behavior? An array would have its members sequentially placed with no padding between them. When you try to read a word, it must get 2*uint8 in a sequence.

Comment: @AkshayImmanuelD: It leads to undefined behavior because it is outside the behavior that the C standard defines. You thinking of it as “This is an array, and I point to elements of it, and the elements are there in memory, and I tell the compiler to use this `uint16` pointer to get an element from memory, so it does.” That is not how it works. A compiler is not required by the C standard to get elements from memory when you use a pointer. The C standard only requires a compiler to make the *observable behavior* of a program work if you obey the rules…

Comment: … If you follow the rules in the C standard, they describe how a program works in an abstract machine (an abstract computer) that the standard defines. That computer has certain observable behavior, largely input and output. The compiler is allowed to change the program in any way it wants, as long as the observable behavior of the changed program is the same as the observable behavior of the original program as defined by the C standard. Since the C standard defines behavior only if you follow the rules, failing to follow the rules means the compiler can make any changes it wants.…

Comment: … The purpose of all this is to allow the compiler to optimize programs. This use of an abstract machine and observable behavior means the compiler is allowed to do make changes for speed or other reasons. For example, if you have a `uint8 *p` and `uint16 *q`, and you do `*p = 3; *q = 4; printf("%d", *p);`, the compiler does not have to load `*p` from memory when doing the `printf`. Because the rules say `*q` cannot change `*p`, the compiler is allowed to assume that `*p` is still 3 even after `*q = 4`. So it can use a copy it keeps in a register instead of reloading it from memory.…

Comment: … If you follow the rules, all the transformations the compiler makes will work; they will not break your program. If you violate the rules, your program may break in ways that seem mysterious.

Comment: How devoted to the C++ world your comments are.. people must know the *fear* of undefined behavior.

Comment: So in any situation,whether it's an array in a struct or just an array, accessing like that is undefined ?

Comment: Also, last doubt. Is it undefined behavior because memory is aligned in banks for quicker access and when we point to an end byte of a bank and try to read a word from that last byte, the program becomes undefined?

Comment: @AkshayImmanuelD: Neither. It is because the compiler assumes you are obeying the rules, and it may therefore alter code as if you were. When the compiler optimizes a program, it is allowed to make any changes that produce the same end results **given the assumption the program has obeyed the rules**. If any part of your program does not obey the rules, the behavior of your program may be changed by optimization. That means your program will no longer do what you expected. **Violating the C rules means your program may be changed in unpredictable ways during compiler optimization.**