# Confusion about array being "zeroed out"

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

static char mem[4];

int main()
{
    int* A = (int*)(mem);

    mem[0] = 0;
    mem[1] = 1;
    mem[2] = 2;
    mem[3] = 3;

    int i;
    A[0] = 5;

    for (i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", mem[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

My question is, why does this print 5 0 0 0 rather than 5 1 2 3? Why is the array "wiped out?"

Comment: `char` and `int` don't have the same sizes. writing the first element of `A` writes all 4 elements of `mem`

Comment: Because you wrote code the violates language constraints, and got yourself some undefined behavior.

Comment: replace with `A[0] = 123456789;` to make it more intuitively understandable.

Comment: `int* A = (int*)(mem);` --> risks _undefined behavior_ per "If the
resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined."  C11dr §6.3.2.3 7

Comment: Congratulations, you've discovered little-endian storage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in your case

```
A[0] = 5;
```

writes `5` as *integer* which has a bigger size than `char` (2,4,8, depends).

Your system seems to be little endian, so 5 is written in the first `char` location, then zeroes.

note that if `sizeof(int)` is 8 (as it can happen on some systems), your code is unsafe and triggers *undefined behaviour* as it overwrites memory past the `mem` array (not to mention possible misalignment issues that may slow down operatons or even *crash* on some processors)

Which is why we must respect the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) to avoid "lying to the compiler", for instance, create an `union` so the compiler can adjust alignment & check sizes.

This other Q&A is related: [What happens when you cast a char * address to int * in C when the address is not word-aligned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775216/what-happens-when-you-cast-a-char-address-to-int-in-c-when-the-address-is-no)

Comment: I am curious; I normally don't write code like this. Is this a violation of the strict aliasing rule?

Comment: @machine_1: It *looks* like a violation, but C and C++ have an *exception* to strict aliasing for `char*` because otherwise reading and writing from disk files or sending over network sockets, and other byte-oriented things like that would not work.

Comment: @ZanLynx - It doesn't look like one, it *is* one. You can use a `char*` to access any object type. You may not use an `int*` to access an object declared as `char[4]`. It's not the same.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Of course you can. How else do you think an `fread` into a char buffer works when you then access it via a struct pointer?

Comment: @ZanLynx - I call it undefined behavior. An implementation is allowed to make it defined, but it's not ISO C that makes it okay

Comment: @StoryTeller: Look at section 6.5.7 in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf
Note that access by "a character type". Also above that bit is this quote "If a value is copied into an object having no declared type using
memcpy or memmove, or is copied as an array of character type[...]"

Comment: @ZanLynx - Access by a character type, and the object *having* a character (array) type, is not the same thing. The OP does access via an `int` type when they write 5.

Comment: @StoryTeller But when the code writes bytes into the character array, that is exactly the same as copying an array of character type. Then using that character array as an integer is perfectly fine.

Comment: @ZanLynx `fread()` does not specify use of a `char*` buffer or a character array.

Comment: @ZanLynx - The C abstract machine doesn't say an access "writes bytes".  6.5.7 is quite clear in what types of access are valid and which are not. Read it carefully, and try not to project an implementation onto the standards wording. I'm not about to spend more time mulling this. Read the standard, I have nothing more to say.

Comment: @ZanLynx: `A[0]=5` does not “write bytes into the character array.” In the terminology of the C standard, it access the objects of the array of `char` through an lvalue of type `int`, and this is expressly prohibited by [C 2011 (N1570) 6.5 7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48800036/298225).

Answer (score 2):

Because in your system `sizeof int` is atleast `4` times that of `sizeof(char)` so it took `4` bytes to overwrite all that you wrote because `A` is a pointer to `int`.(But it can take larger than that) (This is the case that would typically be) In case it is not it is an undefined behavior.

Also note in mind that how we write it is depending upon the endianness. In your case it is little endian. So based on endianness it might differ also. No matter what this has no more than experimental purpose.

Also to give you an idea why it is UB when `sizeof(int)` is greater than `4` - is then you would access via `A[0]` some meory out of this array memory and try to modify it and make changes to it - leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: Could be 4 or 8, OP is probably on a LE system so they'd both give 5.

Comment: It's *at least* 4. The OP didn't print more than the first 4, so we can't really know. A nitpick, but still

Comment: @StoryTeller.: Yes. I edited that. In case it is mpre than 4 it's UB.

Comment: @StoryTeller.: Was looking for standard - earlier comment was missing the point saying that I edited. Correct me if there is any major issue or even importantly any minor one.

Answer (score 2):

Your code exhibits undefined behavior, as you try to alias `char *` type using an `int` pointer. It is a violation of the strict aliasing rule, so your code is simply erroneous.

A `char *` type may alias other pointer types, but not the other way around. So, make sure not to violate the language's constraints.

Answer (score 0):

`int* A = (int*)(mem);` --> risks *undefined behavior* per "If the
resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined."  C11dr §6.3.2.3 7

So the rest of code is moot.

Use a `union` to cope with alignment and anti-aliasing concerns.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  union {
    int i;
    unsigned char mem[sizeof(int)];
  } u;

  for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++) {
    u.mem[i] = i;
    printf("%hhu\t", u.mem[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  u.i = 5;

  for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++) {
    printf("%hhu\t", u.mem[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Output  (may vary on your machine)

```
0   1   2   3   
5   0   0   0
```

Why: Now that *undefined behavior* UB is removed from the code,
 [Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48815201/2410359) good answer explains the differences.